# preg_match kills PHP with core dump / no error displayed: How to improve RegEx?

Tags: php, regex, debugging

I have the following regex:

```
preg_match('/function ([[:alpha:]]{1,3})\((.(?!function ))*getKeywordSuggestValue=function/simU', $foo, $matches);
```

The resulting page is just blank (empty result returned). It looks like the matched block would be very big.

```
500 Server closed connection without sending any data back
Content-Type: text/plain
Client-Date: Fri, 11 Sep 2015 09:35:55 GMT
Client-Warning: Internal response
```

display_errors is on, and when I produce a parse error it is shown. Just not this one.

How can a preg_match kill a PHP script like this?

I am using PHP 5.6

*edit*

While trying to make a CLI script with a MCVE i found and error message:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Here is the reproducible example:

```
<?php

$content = str_repeat('function fo(){ bar; bar; }', 1000) . <<<'EOF'
function cz(h,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r){var x=this;x.setValue=function(a){if(!t.isActive)return;var b=t.Elements.input.value;if(a!=b){t.Elements.input.value=a;}}
x.getValue=function(){if(!t.isActive)return;var a=t.Elements.input.value;a=a.replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/\s+$/,"");a=a.replace(/\\/g,"");if(a){return a;}else{return null;}}
x.getKeywordSuggestValue=function(){if(!t.isActive)return;var a=t.Elements.input.value;a=a.replace(/^\s+/,"").replace(/[\s　]+/g," ");a=a.replace(/\\/g,"");if(a){return a;}else{return null;}}
EOF;

preg_match('/function ([[:alpha:]]{1,3})\((.(?!prototype\.render=function))*getKeywordSuggestValue=function/simU', $content, $matches);

echo 'preg_match passed';
```

After a bit of research I found a probably related PHP bug https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45735

The question is now how to fix the regex to not hit this bug.

Comment: Put: `print_r($matches);` after your `preg_match()` call.

Comment: Check the PHP error log on the server.

Comment: @Rizier123: Does not work. The step after preg_match is just never reached. I verified this with a `die('hard');` after preg_match. Same result. hard is never displayed.

Comment: @Barmar: Nothing there...

Comment: @Alex Show us your **full** and **real** code, so we can reproduce your problem. We need a [**MCVE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from you

Comment: Do you have any `echo` statements in the page? `preg_match` doesn't print anything by itself.

Comment: use this to display error `ini_set('display_errors',1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @Saty: Does not help.

Comment: @Rizier123: Working on it...

Comment: I guess its the regular expression itself

Comment: @Rizier123: I was able to make an example. See edit.

Comment: I got your code to work by making the repetition `(.(?!prototype\.render=function))*` non-capturing: http://ideone.com/YBoD2q However, without the expected result, I can't tell whether it's what you want.

Comment: @nhahtdh I expect "cz"

Comment: @nhahtdh: it works. Can you please post that as an answer?

Comment: @Alex: Modifying your first regex in the question: http://ideone.com/YBoD2q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably due to the engine having to allocate too much space on the stack to keep track of the repeated capturing group `(.(?!function ))*`. Since the capturing group is clearly useless here, changing it to non-capturing group `(?:.(?!function ))*` resolves the segmentation fault problem.

I recommend changing it to `(?:(?!function ).)*` since you should check before consume the character.

A minimal example that reproduces the problem [with capturing group](https://3v4l.org/5Hg1v):

```
print (preg_match('~^(a)*$~', str_repeat('a', 10000) . 'b'));
```

> **Output for hhvm-3.6.1 - 3.9.0**
>
> ```
> 0
> ```
>
> **Output for 7.0.0alpha1 - 7.0.0rc2**
>
> (empty output)
>
> **Output for 5.3.18 - 5.6.13**
>
> ```
> Process exited with code 139.
> ```

and [with non-capturing group](https://3v4l.org/DRCKD):

```
print (preg_match('~^(?:a)*$~', str_repeat('a', 10000) . 'b'));
```

> **Output for 5.3.18 - 5.6.13, hhvm-3.6.1 - 3.9.0**
>
> ```
> 0
> ```
>
> **Output for 7.0.0alpha1 - 7.0.0rc2**
>
> (empty output)

Answer (score -2):

Catastrophic Backtracking - Too much backtracking results in exponential growth in time and memory; PHP seems to be crashing; some other implementations take CPU to 100% and ultimately fail; some let you define a timeout or recursion depth; like C# lets you define a timeout to avoid runaway Regular Expressions.

That '?' seems to be the problem in your expressions causing so much backtracking. I am not sure; but removing ? does make the backtracking go away.

As to how this can be fixed - brush up on RegEx, invest in a tool. I once investigated catastrophic backtracking and found this resource useful - http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html. The site also sells a tool that is excellent in graphically showing the backtracking and hopefully giving you enough hints on how to avoid backtracking.

OR use a sledge hammer - limit the amount of backtracking.

```
ini_set('pcre.backtrack_limit','1000');
```

That *might* serve the purpose; though it would report a 'not match' AFTER doing 1000 backtracks, even if a match could have been found had there been more backtracks allowed.

Comment: Your post doesn't make any sense. There is no `?` in the regular expression, except for `(?!...)`, which means negative look-ahead. Catastrophic backtracking won't cause segmentation fault - the characteristic behavior is exponential run time. On the contrary, I have seen implementations (Java) which gives StackOverflowError on patterns which are free of catastrophic backtracking - the cause is due to large number of repetitions which use up the stack space to keep track of where to backtrack to.

Comment: ok; how do you know that there is no bug that causes segmentation fault on Catastrophic backtracking? Not possible? Why does the fault goes away when you limit the backtracking?

Comment: The fault goes away simply because you indirectly limit the number of repetition by lowering the backtracking limit. You **might** observe this behavior on a catastrophic backtracking pattern, but the cause is due to the implementation of quantifier which allocates too much space. Compare https://3v4l.org/DRCKD and https://3v4l.org/5Hg1v

Comment: and allocating too much space leads to seg fault? Runaway backtracking --> too much space allocated on stack does NOT? What exactly is too much space here? How big is the file? How big can a quantifier become?

Comment: Segmentation fault is a side effect of the implementation of quantifier. It's not a necessary condition of catastrophic backtracking (though it could occur). The thing is - the regex in the question is not a case of catastrophic backtracking, It's the case where the repetition can repeat a large number of times, and the workaround here is not capturing the repeated group.

Comment: The repetition can repeat a large number of times - I though this is what is called catastrophic backtracking. RegEx engine tries with one repetition, fails to find a match, backtracks and tries with lesser repetition and so on. This is what I read as classic catastrophic backtracking. If NOT backtracking, why would RegEx try to "repeat" the repetition a number of times?

Comment: See the link to 3v4l above. They are repeated many times, but not catastrophic backtracking - just a simple `^a*$`. Catastrophic backtracking can occur on `(a*)*` or `a*a*`, since they can match the same substring in multiple ways. For a simple `a*`, there is no catastrophic backtracking.